# Is there a word that means "to turn into a habit"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that represents the action of forming a habit.

As an example:

> Joe wanted to find a way to __________ [*habit-ize*] healthy eating.

Comment: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/make-a-habit-of-something

Comment: Looks like there's no single-word substitute.

Comment: Joe wanted to find a way to form a healthy eating habit.

Comment: to make healthy eating a habit. The simplest way to say this. To make something [something] is a typical form in English. There is not always a single word for everything under the sun.

Comment: @Lambie 'There is not always a single word for everything under the sun.' oh for that to pop up any time [single-word-request] is used!

Comment: The immediately obvious derivation would be ***habitualise***. That would mean ‘make habitual’ or ‘make a habit of’, but it’s [very rare](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=habitualize%2Cmake+a+habit+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chabitualize%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmake%20a%20habit%20of%3B%2Cc0) to say the least. It is in the OED as a derivative of _habitual_, but I wouldn’t advise using it unless you feel ad-hoc derivations (which is what it feels like) are all right in your context.

Comment: Could you please explain more clearly what is wrong with habituate?

Comment: there are habits, which are mindless reflexive things we do without thinking, some good , some bad, some netural  (flossing ones teeth,  biting ones nails, leaving your reading glasses on the TV table) then there are things we resolve and actively buy into ... if we force ourselves to work out everyday it might not be a habit.. just a regular schedule.  We don't have a habit of going to work for instance. "eating healthy" might not exactly be a habit...more a practice ... although "good eating habits" is idomatic...but ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**habitualize**

Not yet in dictionaries, but why wait?  It shows up in exactly this meaning on Google's NGram--to make a habit of.

But! OED to the rescue.  A derivative of habitual.

> haˈbitualize  v. (trans.) to render habitual.
>
> a1774   A. Tucker Light of Nature Pursued (1777) III. iv. 44   With
>   the sole expectation of rivetting and habitualizing the three virtues
>   thereby in our hearts.

Also regularize might be considered.  But habitualize is on target.

Comment: Thank you! I glanced at the OED and didn't see that immediately.

Answer (score 5):

"Joe wanted to find a way to /**adopt**/**embrace**/**take up**/ healthy eating."

> - [**adopt**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/adopt) - to take and follow (a course of action, for example) by choice or assent
> - [**embrace**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/embrace) -  to adopt or support willingly or eagerly
> - [**take up**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/take+up) - to develop an interest in or enter into: *take up mountain climbing*

Comment: "get in the groove", or "make a practice of" , "form routine" are couple other ones for people to consider

Comment: @Tom22   Good call.

Answer (score 0):

***Internalize*** is used in that sense.

> "Joe wanted to find a way to ***internalize*** healthy eating."

**Usage examples**:
[Google search for "internalize healthy eating" (158 results at the time of posting)](https://www.google.com/search?q="internalize+healthy+eating")

ODO:

> **[internalize](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/internalize)**
>   *VERB*
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>   **1** *Psychology*
>   Make (attitudes or behavior) part of one's nature by learning or unconscious assimilation.
>
> ‘At the moment many people have internalised corrupt behaviour as
>   normal in their daily lives.’

Comment: Oops, sorry @Jim! Thanks for the up-vote, though! :)

Comment: internalize is a psychological term.  It does not fit here: Joe wanted to find a way to __________ [habit-ize] healthy eating. In fact, it would sound really silly there.

Comment: @Lambie, so are you saying all psychological terms are forbidden in _regular_ usage? I have certainly seen it used out of _psychological_ contexts and it just happens that ODO lists the definition as _psychological_. Your down-vote is your prerogative but to me it looks rather harsh in this context.

Comment: @alwayslearning Of course not but the psychological terms must make sense or cohere in a sentence. For instance, one internalizes behaviors or a language. One doesn't **internalize healthy eating**. In fact, that sounds almost grotesque....One can internalize the habit of x.

Comment: @Lambie - I disagree. It makes perfect sense to internalize good practices including those of healthy eating.

Comment: 'Internalise healthy eating' is not idiomatic. In fact, it sounds near-ridiculous.

Comment: @Lambie & Edwin Ashworth, added a link to a Google search of the _exact term_ "internalize healthy eating". Possibly all 158 results are silly, grotesque or near-ridiculous. I rest my case.

Comment: I believe "internalize" means to adopt a way of thinking.  I think that is a step away from actually practicing turning an attitude into a practice. By the same token, people do things that they do not mean to or want to out of habit. Our routines and our goals are not always in sync.

Comment: @alwayslearning Lambie and Edwin Ashworth have a secret. They know that if  "internalize healthy eating" flies, so, too, would any activity, and that, frankly, is over the moon. To wit, internalize football playing, or internalize question answering.